# Recovering a file in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I deleted some files of a folder in SVN from eclipse. Now I want those files back to my folder. I can see the of the folder by clicking right click show history . how to get those files back into my workspace? Then I will commit to svn again

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: Did you commit the deletion?

Comment: @alroc yes.. I committed the deletion

Answer (score 0):

No idea how to do that in Eclipse but with plain Subversion that'd be

```
svn checkout
```

and

```
svn cat
```

commands: [the former](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html)
allows you to check out the contents of all or specific
files and the specific revision (usually `BASE`),
and [the latter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html)
outputs the contents of the specified file
at the specified revition (again, usually `BASE`).

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't delete it form remote folder you can simply recover it.

Synchronize the local workspace with remote repository and override the file that you deleted. It will override the local changes of the your file.